# Creating cancel button on UpdateView form

Tags: django

I want to create a `Cancel` button in a update/edit form, but i keep receiving a `AttributeError`exception:

```
'PatientUpdate' object has no attribute 'object'
```

view:

```
class PatientUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = User
    form_class = MyPatientEditForm        
    template_name = "patient/patient_edit.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('patient_list')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if "cancel" in request.POST:
            url = self.get_success_url()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
        else:
            return super(PatientUpdate, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

html:

```
<button class="btn" type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel" />Cancel</button>
```

traceback:

```
Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/braces/views.py" in dispatch
  107.             request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  87.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/Maziar/Dropbox/Sandbox/tutorial/web/views.py" in post
  60.             url = self.get_success_url()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in get_success_url
  133.             url = self.success_url % self.object.__dict__

Exception Type: AttributeError at /patient/edit/3
Exception Value: 'PatientUpdate' object has no attribute 'object'
```

What am i doing wrong exactly? Furthermore i have considered if it would be possible to fetch the `success_url` variable in the template to simply use it in the button without doing the entire `POST` procedure?

**UPDATE:**
The `success_url` works perfectly fine when the form is submitted normally.

Comment: @petkostas, cant be, hence it works when the form reverses when successfull.

Comment: The problem is that the default updateview calls the success url like this:
``if self.success_url:
        url = self.success_url % self.object.__dict__``
Make sure you have a self.object instance ``self.object = self.get_object()`` or just return a HttpResponseRedirect with a custom made url at that time without calling the ``self.get_success_url()``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_success_url` depends on actually having the object. Try this:

```
def post(...):
    if "cancel" in request.POST:
        self.object = self.get_object()
        # ...
```

That way, `get_success_url` will have access to the instance you were editing and the redirect should work.

Getting the success url to the template should work, too:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    kwargs['success_url'] = self.get_success_url()
    return super(..., self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 8):

If user press "Cancel" button he redirected to patients list? So why not to create simple link without any additional logic:

```
<a href="{% url 'patient_list' %}">Cancel</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I 've changed the submit_line.html template, and using the request.META.HTTP_REFERER can get back to the previous changelist (with filtering information!) where you came from:

```
<div class="submit-row">
 {% if show_save %}
 <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save' %}" class="default" name="_save" />{% endif %}
   {% if show_delete_link %}
    {% url opts|admin_urlname:'delete' original.pk|admin_urlquote as delete_url %}
    <p class="deletelink-box"><a href="{% add_preserved_filters delete_url %}" class="deletelink">{% trans "Delete" %}</a></p>
   {% endif %}
   {% if show_save_as_new %}<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save as new' %}" name="_saveasnew" />{% endif %}
   <a href="{{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER }}"><input type="button" name="Cancel" value="Cancel"></a>
   {% if show_save_and_continue %}<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save and continue editing' %}" name="_continue" name="_continue" />{% endif %}
</div>
```